# bootstrap navigation with collapsible search

Tags: navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a navigation with collapsible search box in bootstrap, like wordpress twenty fourteen theme navigation can any one help me?
I want navigation something like this,

[image]

Comment: can you show what code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much of that nav you want to duplicate, it's really just some tweaks to already existing bootstrap nav. But since duplicating the collapse-bar is tricky (for me anyways) here's a way using two search inputs, showing only one at a time, depending on device. And a popover for the tablet+ search.

**[Here's a Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VJW5mTuTEf)**

Search on tablet and larger (`hidden-xs` hides this search bar on phone):

```
  <a id="example" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn hidden-xs pull-right btn-link btn-blk" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="
    <form class='form-inline' role='search'>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Search'>
      </div>
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Go!</button>
    </form>" data-container="body">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a>
```

Search on phone only:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left visible-xs" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Like I said.. not sure how much you want the styling to match your screenshots, but that's pretty close:)